# How to manipulate string within a given index? java

Tags: java

Hi so I am trying to replace the digits in a string with the corresponding roman numeral, and the method should only manipulate the string between the given startPos and endPos.

For example, if the string is:
 **"H3ll0, wh4t 15 ar3 you do1n9"** and startPos = 1, endPos = 14

it should print out: **"HIIIll0, whIVt IV ar3 you do1n9"**

Here is my method:

```
 public void convertToRoman(int startPos, int endPos){   

    for (int i = startPos-1; i < endPos; i++) {
        if (romanNum.contains("1")) {
            romanNum = romanNum.replace("1", "I");
        }
        if (romanNum.contains("2")) {
            romanNum = romanNum.replace("2", "II");
        }
        if (romanNum.contains("3")) {
            romanNum = romanNum.replace("3", "III");
        }
        if (romanNum.contains("4")) {
            romanNum = romanNum.replace("4", "IV");
        }
        if (romanNum.contains("5")) {
            romanNum = romanNum.replace("5", "V");
        }
        if (romanNum.contains("6")) {
            romanNum = romanNum.replace("6", "VI");
        }
        if (romanNum.contains("7")) {
            romanNum = romanNum.replace("7", "VII");
        }
        if (romanNum.contains("8")) {
            romanNum = romanNum.replace("8", "VIII");
        }
        if (romanNum.contains("9")) {
            romanNum = romanNum.replace("9", "IX");
        }
    }

    System.out.print(romanNum);

    }
```

***btw right now it is manipulating the whole string regardless of the given index

Answer (score 0):

The next way would be nice.

```java
char[] chars = romanNum.toCharArray();
String s = "";
for (int i = startPos-1; i < endPos; i++) {
    if (chars[i] == '1') {
            s += "I";
    }
    if (chars[i] == '2') {
            s += "II";
    }
    ...
    else {
            s += chars[i]
    }
}
System.out.print(s);
```

Comment: but 'II' is not a char though

Comment: oh..I fixed it.

Comment: this also doesn't return the whole string

Answer (score 0):

You can do like there.

```
String a = "H3ll0, wh4t 15 ar3 you do1n9";
int startPos = 1;
int endPos = 14;
String beginSubstring = a.substring(0,startPos);
String substring = a.substring(startPos, endPos);
String lastSubstring = a.substring(endPos);

String resultOperation =operation(substring);
String result = beginSubstring+resultOperation+lastSubstring;
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.replace` replaces the first instance of the found match, it does not have any index bounds for the replacement.  Instead you should loop through the individual characters in the String and replace them one at a time if they match the replacement;

```java
 Map<Character, String> replacements = new HashMap<>();
 replacements.put('1', "I");
 replacements.put('2', "II");
 replacements.put('3', "III");
//etc
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(romanNum.length());
if (startPos > 0) {
   sb.append(romanNum, 0, startPos);
}

for(int i=startPos; i <= endPos; i++) {
  char c = romanNum.charAt(i);
  sb.append(replacements.getOrDefault(c, Character.toString(c)));
}
if (endPos + 1 < romanNum.length()) {
  sb.append(romanNum.substring(endPos + 1));
}
String result = sb.toString();
```